# Where does the error term of a time series MA process come from?

Tags: time-series, moving-average

Consider an MA(1) process:
$$
Y_t = a + a_1u_t + a_2u_{t-1} 
$$
where $a$ is some constant, and $u_t$ is an error term.

How do we know know the error terms? They must come from some previous regression, right?

P.S. I've read [What can be an intuitive understanding of the error term of a moving average time series?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241732/what-can-be-an-intuitive-understanding-of-the-error-term-of-a-moving-average-tim) but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: "How do we know" is vague.  Are you asking about how to *estimate* the $u_t$ or about their *meaning* and *interpretation*?  Or maybe your question is something else?

Comment: I meant to say, how do we find them? They are residuals of what regression?

Comment: I'm sorry, that phrase is still vague: could you explain what you mean by "find" and tell us why you keep referring to "regression"?

Comment: Let me try this way, I know that I am missing something, but that's what this community is after all.

Error terms come out form some regression, right. That's what they are by definition: difference between observed and fitted values. Also, real error terms are not observable, because we do not know PRF (Population Regression Function), so we can only observe ut (hat), as difference between SRF (Rample Regression Function) and observed values. That's the reason why i'm keep referring to ''regression''. And in MA() errors are regressors, so how do we find them?

Comment: *Residuals* are the differences between observed and fitted values, in any statistical model. They *are* observable. *Error terms* are theoretical quantities, almost always in the form of random variables, used to account for potential discrepancies between observations and what a *deterministic* model might predict.  As such, error terms are part of a model.  Your terms $u_t$ and $u_{t-1}$ are error terms, not residuals, and have no inherent relationship to regression. They are part of the model: they cannot be "found," but they can be reasoned about and estimated from data (if you have any).

Comment: Well then, first question is: Is there any logic about why are they used in MA process, before we continue to the process of their estimation?

Comment: The "logic" is that this is what an MA process is!

Comment: 'Error terms are theoretical quantities, almost always in the form of random variables, used to account for potential discrepancies between observations and what a deterministic model might predict.'

What I was trying to ask is on what deterministic model are error terms in above MA model based? Also, should MA model have its own errors i.e.:

Yt = a + a1*ut + a2*ut-1 + ɛt, ɛt being error of MA process.

Comment: The deterministic model is what is left when those terms are omitted (or set to zero): $Y_t=a$.  This MA(2) model describes serially correlated random fluctuations around the constant value $a$.

Comment: Thank you. So if I try to concretize it on next example :

t:   1   2   3   4   5   6 
Yt: 2   3   4   2   1   5
a = mean(Yt) = 2.83
residuals: -0.83 0.17 1.17 -0.83 -1.83 2.17

Why we do not use these residuals as error term proxies but we have to estimate them instead?

Comment: All you have is data $Y_t$.  You don't know $a$, you don't know the $a_i$, and you don't know any of the $u_t$.  Thus you have to estimate them--there's no away around that. It's not at all evident that the mean of $Y_t$ is the best or even a good estimator of $a$.